# Updating using basic SQL without lead and lag as sybase ASE does not support it

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to write a query to update a table based on below:

Let's say we have below table

```
Name  |Account  |Currency |Balance |
Sahil |Account1 |USD      |40,000  |
Rohan |Account2 |USD      |30,000  |
Mohit |Account3 |USD      |20,000  |
Ronak |Account4 |USD      |10,000  |
John  |Account5 |EUR      |50,000  |
Ram   |Account6 |EUR      |40,000  |
```

I want to deduct a total of $90,000. Firstly, I will deduct only from accounts having currency as USD because the amount which I want to deduct is in USD. Secondly, the way i want to deduct is start from the account which has the highest amount.

In my example I start with `account1` and deduct 40,000 and so on and so forth. After deduction, as per the example, I should have exhausted amounts in all of the accounts except account4. The table after deduction will look like below:

```
Name  |Account  |Currency |Balance |
Sahil |Account1 |USD      |     0  |
Rohan |Account2 |USD      |     0  |
Mohit |Account3 |USD      |     0  |
Ronak |Account4 |USD      |10,000  |
John  |Account5 |EUR      |50,000  |
Ram   |Account6 |EUR      |40,000  |
```

Same goes for Euro.

Is it possible to write a generic query where currency is my key without cursor?

I don't want hardcode currency in my query.

Using Sybase ASE which does not support lead and lag or any advanced feature. Is it possible with basic query?

Comment: what query(s) have you tried so far?

Comment: for ASE: while it's possible to write a single query to use a variable (eg, `update ... where Currency = @currency`), and it's possible to write a single query to distribute the amount (eg, `90,000`) across multiple rows, I'm not aware of any 'basic/easy' query that allows you to apply an `order by` clause to a UPDATE statement (ie, ASE does not support `update ... order by ...`)